# Swagger and Jenkins integration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, swagger, swagger-ui

So we have Swagger UI and YAML file manually generated by a developer. The plan is to use Jenkins to validate our API endpoints (request and response schemas) using the Swagger schema. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean validating the manually generated YAML file using Jenkins?

Comment: yes. The YAML file is being generated manually. Then we would like to plug that into Jenkins and validate the schema based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Sagger Diff. This CLI tool shows breaking changes between 2 different swagger json files

http://swagger.io/using-swagger-to-detect-breaking-api-changes/